# Set Section Visible if Checkbox is checked

Tags: checkbox, orbeon

I want to know how to make a particular section visible or expanded automatically when a check box is ticked in Orbeon forms. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an [XPath expression](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/). Suppose:

- The section has a control name = `control-1`
- The checkboxes has the control name = `control-2`
- The specific checkbox you're interested has a value = `my-value`

Then, in the Section Settings for the relevant section you can set the Visibility to the following XPath expression:

```
xxf:split($control-2) = 'my-value'
```

Comment: @n.path Also, if instead of checkboxes you're using a *Yes/No Answer* control, then the XPath expression would be: `$control-2/string() = 'true'`.